# How to Delete rows from SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection C#

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint-clientobject

I have taken the data in ListItemCollection from SharePoint client object.

Now I am looking for some solution by which I can remove some rows(ListItem) temporary from ListItemCollection based on some column value.

This should delete rows from ListItemCollection which is in memory not from Sharepoint list.

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just populate a new ListItemCollection with the ones you want returned from SharePoint

Comment: If I again populate then I need to hit sharepoint again where I am already taken the data. So it will hamper the performance as it takes 3 seconds to get the data from SP.

Comment: I meant take the listitemcollection you are getting from sharepoint and filter that list into a new list

Comment: If I filter the listitemcollection, it returns IEnumerable<ListItem> on which I can not perform delete operation on memory collection.